# How to stop the page refreshing after button click in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

**What I need**

I need to stop the page refreshing while user click submit button in MVC.

**Still what I done**

log in page with refreshing using jquery.if click a submit button on  the page is refreshing and it display the welcome message with username. but I want the same functionality without refreshing the page

**Error:**

submit a button the page is postback

*Controller:*

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(LoginMVC u) {

  if (ModelState.IsValid) // this is check validity
  {
    using(LoginAndSignUpEntities dc = new LoginAndSignUpEntities()) {
      var v = dc.tbl_Detailstbl.Where(a => a.Email_Id.Equals(u.EmailId) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
      if (v != null) {
        Session["LogedUserID"] = v.Email_Id.ToString();
        Session["LogedUserFullname"] = v.Name.ToString();        
      }
    }
  }
  return Json(u, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

*View:*

```
<button id="model" style="border:none;">login</button>

<div id="my-dialog">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "ID" })) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken() // this is for prevent CSRF attack @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">

      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailId, new { @id = "txtuserid" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailId)     
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
     @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @id = "txtpassword" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnlogin" />
    </p>
  </div>
  }
</div>
```

*Script:*

```
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  $("#btnlogin").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#txtuserid').val();
    var password = $('#txtpassword').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")', 
      type: 'POST',
      data:  $(this).serialize(),
      datatype: "json",
      success: function() {
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("error123");
      }
    });

  });
});           
</script>
```

*popup script:*

```
$(function() {
  $("#login_page").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    },
  });
  $("#model").click(function() {
    $("#login_page").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

please give me a solution for this issue....

Comment: Why don't you do this to serialise the form data to your model in the ajax call: data: $(this).serialize()

Comment: You need to also return false at the end to stop the form submit behaviour

Comment: yes.  I changed my code but it also post back again

Answer (score 3):

#### Updates:

Just noticed that you have bound `submit` event on the submit button. Which is incorrect.

`submit` event should be bound on `form`:

```
$("#my-dialog form").submit(function (e){

        e.preventDefault();
         // put all other code here

 });
```

---

`.preventDefault()` is the actual method, as i can see there is a typo in `e.preventdefault()` which should be corrected to:

```
e.preventDefault(); // look for upperCase D not d
```

So, when you click on the button it stops at `e.preventdefault()` as this is not found in the event object and script execution stops which caused in a postback.

Answer (score 0):

**@Jai** has the correct answer for your issue (+1).

But I would also recommend changing your handler to

```
$("#ID").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

As if a user pressed enter in one of the fields, then that would submit the form, bypassing your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the return false in your code to stop the default submit behaviour?

As of jQuery 1.5 you should work with the promise interface methods of done, fail and always.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$("#btnlogin").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

// Get the form
var $this = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    datatype: "json"
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert("success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert("fail");
  });

  return false;
});
```